# iOS and AudioKit - Display FFT with AKNodeFFTPlot: how to limit the frequency range?

Tags: swift, fft, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit for frequency detection. This works very fine!
In addition, I want to display the FFT spectrum as a graph, thus I rely on **AKNodeFFTPlot** which enables us to plot the spectrum in an UIView.

My problem: it seems that it isn't possible to limit the x-axis to a value - let's say 500 Hz.
When I produce a sound (for example with my guitar), only very narrow peaks at the very left-hand side appear - the user can't see the difference between 100 Hz and 1000 Hz because the output is compressed.

My question: does anyone know if there's a workaround? The API doesn't seem to offer possibilities of reducing the frequency range - or even better - display the x-axis in a logarithmic way. Any help or hint appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any luck with that?

Comment: figure it out?..